# How to set the same rounded corner to linear layouts?

Tags: android, layout, android-drawable, cornerradius

I'm trying to make a single bar chart using Linear Layout (don't want to use MPAndroidChart or other libraries).

This is something i'd like to achieve:
[image]

[image]

So as you can see, the corners have the same degree/radius, no matter the width of the layout.

Here is what I did: 
[image]

Which looks good, but here comes the problem: When having this Linear Layout with a smaller width, then the radius doesn't work the way I wanted 
[image]

I would like to have the same radius angle on both, something like this (the blue part should but cut off):
[image]

I was hoping that I can set the `radius` property with some perecent, but this is not possible. Here is the layout:

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_statistics_budgeting_recycler_view_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bar_chart_total"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_statistics_budgeting_recycler_view_category_image">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_statistics_budgeting_recycler_view_bar_chart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_bar_chart_spent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the two `drawable` files (the only difference is the color):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- rounded_bar_chart_total-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="48dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
        android:left="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
        android:right="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
        android:top="@dimen/margin_extra_small" />
    <solid android:color="#8FEFEEEC" />
</shape>
```

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--rounded_bar_chart_spent-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="48dp" />
    <solid android:color="#5CE662" />
</shape>```

Any help how to do this?
````

Comment: They are clearly not the same since the foist one has padding which i think is unnecessary, the second xml is more than fine, if you need padding why not on adding on the linear layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to hardcode the progress bar by yourself. It seems that `material components library` implemented this (requires `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`). Check [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/ProgressIndicator.md) for github doc and here is an example I did:

```
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/linearProgressIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false" // static progress bar
        android:progress="50"
        app:trackCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:trackThickness="20dp" />
```